# Deduce PDF of $1/X$ from PDF of $X$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Assume that we have a pdf $f(x)$ with random variable $X.$ How can you find the pdf of the random variable $Y = 1/X$?
I checked some examples including Cauchy distribution and I saw Jacobian in Cauchy distribution's exapmle.

Anyway, for or example if we have a cdf $F(x)$ with random variable $X,$ and if we want to find the cdf of r.v. $Y = aX+b,$ we do the following:

$$F(x) = P( X \le x ) \Longrightarrow F(y) = P( Y \le y ) = P( aX+b \le y ) = P\left( X \le \frac{y-b}a \right).$$

How about $Y = 1/X$?

Comment: So $P(Y \leq y) = P(1/X \leq y)$, and you know $P(X \leq x)$ for any $x$, and hence $P(X > x)$ for any $x$. You can use the same technique: $P(Y \leq y) = P(X \geq 1/y)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $X$ is always positive you can say
\begin{align}
f_Y(y)& =\frac{d}{dy}\Pr\left( Y\le y\right) = \frac d{dy}\Pr\left(X\ge \frac 1 y\right) = \frac{d}{dy} \left(1-F_X\left(\frac 1 y\right)\right) \\[10pt]
& = -f_X\left(\frac 1 y\right)\cdot\frac d {dy}\,\frac 1 y \\[10pt]
& = f_X\left(\frac 1 y\right)\cdot \frac 1 {y^2}
\end{align}
and then do simplifications that depend on which function $f$ is.

But that won't work for the Cauchy distribution.  You have to do it piecewise, considering positive and negative parts separately.

(And if $X\sim\mathrm{Cauchy}$ then $1/X\sim\mathrm{Cauchy}$.  If you're collecting the basic facts about this distribution, then include that one.)

Comment: This is wrong, $\frac{d}{dy}\Pr\left( Y\le y\right) \ne \frac d{dy}\Pr\left(X\le \frac 1 y\right)$ and so there should be no minus sign in the final answer.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\vert\left\vert\, #1\,\right\vert\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\tt\mbox{The easy way}\ldots}$

\begin{align}
&\pp\pars{y}\,\dd y=\,{\rm P}\pars{x}\,\dd x\ \imp\
\pp\pars{y}\verts{-\,{\dd x \over x^{2}}}=\,{\rm P}\pars{x}\,\verts{\dd x}\ \imp\
\color{#66f}{\large\pp\pars{y}}=\,{\rm P}\pars{x}x^{2}
\\[5mm]&=\color{#66f}{\large{\,{\rm P}\pars{1/y} \over y^{2}}}
\end{align}

Comment: Is this mathematics at all?

Answer (score 0):

The univariate transformation formula is this:

For $Y=g(X)$, $f_Y(y)=f_X(g^{-1}(y))|(g^{-1})'(y)|$.

Applied to $Y=\frac{1}{X}$, this gives:

$f_Y(y)=\frac{f_X(\frac{1}{y})}{y^2}$.

Comment: Under which conditions can we use this formula?

Comment: Well, the normal stuff can go wrong, like if you're using a distribution with positive probability concentrated right at $0$. There are some other pathological examples, but you should be fine with smooth transformations of the standard random variables.

Comment: @George, maybe you should consider to consult a textbook. They are there to learn the basics.